# Unable to set static IP on embedded with ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, dhcp, embedded-system

I have a Wandboard embedded system with ubuntu 16.04 (I think it is the minimal version) and kernel 4.9.35. I have been trying to set an static IP but I have not managed to do it. I have been searching, but no matter what I try, it does not work.

First, my /etc/network/interfaces looks like:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
#source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.2.5
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast 192.168.2.255
network 192.168.2.0
gateway 192.168.2.129
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
```

There was a daemon called udhcpd running, so I disabled it with update.rc. NetworkManager is not installed.

Running
    ps aux | grep dhcp
shows nothing. A similar search with the term "netw" or "etw" (to see if NetworkManager is working, or something similar) returns nothing either. Searching for "ip" returns

```
root        99  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   14:38   0:00 [ipv6_addrconf]
```

But it should only affect ipv6...

isc-dhcp-client and isc-dhcp-common were installed, so I removed them. Nothing.

Any other ideas?

Thank you.

EDIT: If I login first through a serial port, without the ethernet cable connected, it sets correctly the IP (192.168.2.5). If I connect the ethernet cable before logging in, it get the IP from the dhcp server (192.168.2.2XX, the range of the dhcp server). Any guess?

Comment: Why are you sure it didn't work? What does `ifconfig` say? And does `sudo service networking status` display any errors?

Comment: Are you sure about the gateway address?

Comment: I always have to smile when people use network and broadcast, when they are already specified a netmask address. Like others asked, what does your `ifconfig` say?

Comment: Yes, the gateway is a wrt-54gl with dd-wrt with the ip address 192.168.2.129. This router has a DHCP server that provides ip's staring in 192.168.2.200. The embedded linux gets the ip address 192.168.2.203.

Comment: My ifconfig: 
Eth0
Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1f:7b:45:13:ab  
inet addr:192.168.2.203  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
inet6 addr: fe80::21f:7bff:feb4:acb/64 Scope:Link
UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST DYNAMIC  MTU:1500  Metric:1
RX packets:217 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:179 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
RX bytes:23452 (23.4 KB)  TX bytes:25491 (25.4 KB)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found that connman was the responsible when I looked at /etc/resolv.conf

I solved it with:

```
sudo apt-get remove connman
sudo reboot
```